# Parsley options not getting applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

I have a form that does *not* include the `data-parsley-validate` attribute so it is not made a Parsley form before calling the .parsley() function as shown below.

I also have this JavaScript that initializes Parsley with my form:

```
$('#reg-form').parsley({
  successClass: 'success',
  errorClass: 'error',
  errors: {
     errorsWrapper: '<span class=\"help-block\"></span>',
     errorElem: '<span></span>'
  }

});
```

However, if I fill out the form so it isn't valid, the error messages still show up in the default `ul` list, and my success and error classes are not used.

I have a lot of form elements in this form, so instead of using the DOM API, I'd like to use JavaScript to override that option for every form element.

I'm using Parsley `2.0.0-rc4` with jQuery `2.0.3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silly mistake on my part. The errors options don't belong in the `errors` key. The example I worked from was wrong or outdated.

Working example:

```
$('#reg-form').parsley({
  successClass: 'success',
  errorClass: 'error',
  errorsWrapper: '<span class=\"help-block\"></span>',
  errorElem: '<span></span>'
});
```

Comment: Where did you find the new documentation for this? i've been searching for hours and no result yet